# What wide-characters are translated into a null multibyte?

Tags: c, widechar

According to the [reference for wcstombs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/wcstombs/), wcstombs will translate wide-characters "until a wide character translates into a null character."

So what wide-characters are translated into a null multibyte? Is it a specific character? Or any character outside a given range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wcstombs` function will translate until the `L'\0'` character (the wide character NUL) is encountered in the wide string (or until the destination multibyte string is filled).  That documentation describes what it does when it encounters an error.